# How to use custom properties as a color panel?

Tags: python, materials, color, properties

Here is my problem : i would like to store color data in my blender files and be able to switch between all colors for my object with a python script. So i tried to create custom properties for every color, with a "main property" which is linked to my materials. And then i would like to create a script to copy the RGB values of the stored colors and paste those values in my "Main Property".

The goal is to have a system that can be used for any type of object, no matter how much materials or colors it has : just change the "color" property and it will change every material using this color.

But is it possible ? And how can i write it in script ?

EDIT : In fact, I just want a way to change the base color of several materials with a python script. So if there is a simpler way to do so... XD

---

Thanks for your answers !

I finally successed to create a python script that works. The simplest way, maybe not the best. I created a "Main Color" property and a bunch of color properties and scripted it like this :

```
bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["MainColor"][0]=bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["9440"][0]
bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["MainColor"][1]=bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["9440"][1]
bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["MainColor"][2]=bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["9440"][2]
bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["MainColor"][3]=bpy.data.objects["MonObjet"]["9440"][3]
```

"9440" is the color reference, and MainColor is the driver pasted on all my materials. So my script just copy/paste the values of the stored color on the "MainColor" Property.

What do you think, is there a better way to do ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use series of bool properties (as elements of a collection) which allows to have an **active item** and also **trigger an event** by using the `update` function of each `BoolProperty`.

Each `BoolProperty` can be displayed as an icon and the icon itself can be **generated on the fly** by adding a new [preview collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.previews.html#bpy.utils.previews.ImagePreviewCollection) and then assigning a pixel array to each new *icon* added: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ImagePreview.html

[image]

Example of a custom color palette using `BoolProperties`. When a color is selected from the list, the color is assigned to **base color** of the principled shader and the diffuse color of all materials.

```
import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        active_item = None
        for idx, item in enumerate(scn.color_collection, start=1):
            row.prop(item, "active", icon_value=item.icon, icon_only=True)
            if item.active == True:
                active_item = item
            if idx % 11 == 0:
                row = col.row(align=True)
            
        if active_item:
            row = layout.row()
            r, g, b, a = active_item.color
            row.label(text=f"Active item: {r:.2f} {g:.2f} {b:.2f} {a:.2f}")                


def update_callback(self, context):
    if self.active:
        for i in self.id_data.color_collection:
            if i.name != self.name:
                i.active = False
    
    # set the diffuse and base color for all materials
    for slot in context.object.material_slots:
        material = slot.material
        material.diffuse_color = self.color
        if material.use_nodes:
            for node in material.node_tree.nodes:
                if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
                    node.inputs['Base Color'].default_value = self.color

class ColorCollection(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # name: bpy.props.StringProperty
    active: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False, update=update_callback)
    icon: bpy.props.IntProperty()
    color: bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
         name = "Color",
         subtype = "COLOR",
         default = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),
         size = 4)

# We can store multiple preview collections here,
# however in this example we only store "main"
preview_collections = {}

color_palette = [
    (0.46, 0.41, 0.62, 1),
    (0.67, 0.18, 0.34, 1),
    (0.64, 0.10, 0.91, 1),
    (0.66, 0.09, 0.01, 1),
    (0.86, 0.90, 0.90, 1),
    (0.95, 0.27, 0.83, 1),
    (0.53, 0.08, 0.78, 1),
    (0.47, 0.27, 0.61, 1)]


def register():
    
    # register the classes
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColorCollection)
    bpy.types.Scene.color_collection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=ColorCollection)
    
    # clear the collection
    if hasattr(bpy.context.scene, "color_collection"):
        bpy.context.scene.color_collection.clear()
        
    # generate colors and icons
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    
    size = 32, 32
    for i, color in enumerate(color_palette):
        
        color_name = f"Color{i}"
        pixels = [*color] * size[0] * size[1]
        icon = pcoll.new(color_name) # name has to be unique!
        icon.icon_size = size
        icon.is_icon_custom = True
        icon.icon_pixels_float = pixels
        
        # add the item to the collection
        color_item = bpy.context.scene.color_collection.add()
        color_item.name = color_name
        color_item.color = color
        color_item.icon = pcoll[color_name].icon_id
        
    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    

def unregister():
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()
    
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColorCollection)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    
    del bpy.types.Scene.color_collection


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you prefer to use an **operator instead of the update function**, see one of my previous answers to: [How to display a fixed list of RGB values in a panel and when a color is clicked call an operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252436/139380)

Comment: Regarding your edit: See line 38 for how to change the base color for all materials in the slot list or maybe [How to change base color of a Principled BSDF Material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250747/how-to-change-base-color-of-a-principled-bsdf-material)