# Turning a csv with RGB values into a 3D array

Tags: modifiers, csv

I have a csv file with lots of RGB colours (in 3 columns, r, g, b). I want to use that data to make an array of cubes, one cube per RGB value. I want to use the RGB to specify the x,y,z coordinates *and* ideally the colour of the cube material. (This second step is less important; I'd be happy with just the first step for now.)

This intuitively feels like a do-able thing, but I'm a noob in Blender and from watching some tutorials on using csv data, I don't feel I understand enough to adapt any techniques to doing this problem. Grateful for any help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101299/render-100k-objects-each-with-independent-color-and-scale-through-time https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76535/create-model-from-xyz-data-points/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head over to the `Scripting` tab, create a new python file and paste this code (of course change `<your path to>` to your locations):

```
import bpy
import csv

with open('<your path to>/rgb.csv') as csvfile:
    
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    
    currline = -1
    for row in reader:
        currline += 1
        
        if currline == 0: # ignore header line
            print(f'columns: {" ".join(row)}')
            continue
            
        r = float(row[0])
        g = float(row[1])
        b = float(row[2])

        volume = 10 # span cubes in space
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
            enter_editmode = False,
            size     = 1,
            align    = 'WORLD',
            location = (r * volume, g * volume, b * volume), # use (r g b) for (x y z)
            scale    = (1, 1, 1)
        )
        bpy.context.active_object.name = 'row ' + str(currline)   # name cube with data row
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = str(r) + ',' +str(g) + ',' + str(b)) # name mat with (r g b)
        mat.diffuse_color = (r, g, b, 1)
        
        bpy.context.active_object.data.materials.append(mat)
```

With a test *.csv* layouted like so

```
r,g,b,
0.1,0.1,1,
0.1,0.2,1,
0.1,0.3,1,
0.6,0.1,0.4,
0.7,0.1,0.2,
0.1,0.1,0.5,
```

you get the following result:

[image]

**Edit:** `diffuse_color` is only the color in the viewport, which may raise confusion. Changing the "real" color takes a bit more like described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250747/how-to-change-base-color-of-a-principled-bsdf-material).

Comment: Amazing, thank you, that works! With the colour, I realise now that as well as changing the real colour as you mention in your edit, the RGB data is in 0-255 format, so I'll also need to convert it to 0-1.

Comment: You can also use the more pythonic `for currline, row in enumerate(reader):` which takes care of incrementing the variable